# Trigger On Opportunity to update custom object

Tags: trigger, custom-object, opportunity, custom

New in trigger.

Opportunity 
Standard field :CloseDate
Custom Field :Status(Status_c) (picklist)

Custom Object :Customer(Customer__c)
custom field : Contract Close Date(Contract_Close_Date)

when Opportunity status field is updated to Accepted, then customer field contract field should be updated to close date.
there is master detail relationship.

Trigger:

```
trigger ContractDate on Opportunity ( after update) { 
List <ID> opps=New List<ID>(); 
for(Opportunity o:Trigger.new){ 
if(o.Status__c=='Approved'){ 
    opps.add(o.Id); 
} 
} 
Customer__c customerList=[SELECT Id,Contract_End_Date__c FROM Customer__c WHERE id in:opps]; 
for(Customer__c cst:customerList){ 
customerList.Contract_End_Date__c=Opps.CloseDate; 
update cst; 
} 
}
```

Comment: You don't need a trigger here. It can be achieved by process builder.

Comment: yes , but i want to give try with trigger any suggestion?

Comment: If you want to do it via a trigger please share what you have already tried, we are happy to help with specific problems but won't write it for you.

Comment: trigger ContractDate on Opportunity ( after update) {
  List <ID> opps=New List<ID>();
      
    for(Opportunity o:Trigger.new){
        if(o.Status__c=='Approved'){
            opps.add(o.Id);
           
        }
    }
    
    Customer__c customerList=[SELECT Id,Contract_End_Date__c FROM Customer__c WHERE id in:opps];
 
    
    for(Customer__c cst:customerList){
       customerList.Contract_End_Date__c=Opps.CloseDate;
         update cst;
    }
   

}

Comment: not able to post it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trigger ContractDate on Opportunity ( after update) {
    set <ID> oid=New set<ID>(); 
    list<Customer__c> updatecust=new list<Customer__c>();
    for(Opportunity opp:Trigger.new){ 
        if(opp.Status__c=='Approved'){
            oid..add(opp.Id);
        } 

        list<Customer__c> custlist=[SELECT Id,Contract_End_Date__c FROM Customer__c WHERE id in:oid]; 
        for(Customer__c cust:custList){ 
            cust.Contract_End_Date__c=Opp.CloseDate; 
            updatecust.add(cust);
        }
    }
    update updatecust; 
}
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: It Worked , there is Minor change . in custlist (WHERE id in) to (WHERE Opportunity__c in )

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I could found some issues in your code. You are querying in Customers by checking its id with Opportunity ids. You need a map to hold opportunity id and closedate values.

```
trigger ContractDate on Opportunity (after update) { 
     Map<Id, Date> oppMap = New Map<Id, Date>(); 
     for(Opportunity o :Trigger.new){ 
          if(o.Status__c == 'Approved'){ 
               oppMap.put(o.Id, o.CloseDate); 
          } 
     } 
     List<Customer__c> customers = new List<Customer__c>();
     //---Use correct fieldname for Opportunity__c lookup---//
     for(Customer__c cst : [SELECT Id, Contract_End_Date__c, Opportunity__c FROM Customer__c WHERE Opportunity__c IN :oppMap.keySet()]){ 
          cst.Contract_End_Date__c = oppMap.get(cst.Opportunity__c); 
          customers.add(cst);
     } 
     UPDATE customers; 
}
```

Note:

- Avoid DML inside loops.
- Always have a handler class for each trigger. Code should be added in handler class and call it form trigger by passing [trigger context variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm).
- Avoid unwanted collection variables. You can query in loop itself.